# Segmentation fault when reading a vector

Tags: c++, stl

in a c++ program, when I want to read a vector with the size of 2697806, I always get the Segmentation fault error. 
I have had tried all possible ways of reading it:

```
void AUROC(vector<float> v) {
   ...
   for(std::vector<int>::size_type i = 0; i != v.size(); i++)
      if (v[i]>0) ++pos; else ++neg;

   for(std::vector<long>::size_type i = 0; i != v.size(); i++)
     if (v[i]>0) ++pos; else ++neg;

   for (vector<float>::iterator i=v.begin(); i!=v.end(); ++i)
     if (*i>0) ++pos; else ++neg;

   for (long i=0;i<=v.size();i++)
     if (v[i]>0) ++pos; else ++neg;

   for(int i=0;i<=v.size();i++)
     if (v[i]>0) ++pos; else ++neg;
}

...
int main(void) { 
    vector<float> scores;
    // put data in scores;
    AUROC(scores);
}
```

**this problem never happens with the vectors of much smaller sizes.**

Thanks for your help.
Best,
Pegah

Comment: Please show the code where you add stuff to `v`.

Comment: "in a c program, when I want to read a vector" Awesome, C has vectors now! =D

Comment: vector<float> scores;

scores.push_back((1==1 ) ? s : (-s));

Comment: I send the result of scores to another function, void AUROC(vector<float> v)  in this way: AUROC(scores);

Comment: dont pass it by value, but by reference or by pointer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it works for smaller sizes, my best guess is that you're running out of stack space. How to check the stack space and changing it depends on your OS: On Linux run `ulimit -s` to check and `ulimit -s SIZE` to set.

Further reading: http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/79-the-stack-and-the-heap/

Comment: @Pegah, You need to make your `ulimit -s` tens bigger. E.g. `ulimit -s 70000000`. And check it by `ulimit -s` command

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It is a network. And I can't change it to more than this amount. now it even don't allow me to change it to 2900000! bash: ulimit: stack size: cannot modify limit: This function is not permitted.

Comment: So if you can't make your stack bigger than 3 MB, don't put 30 MB of data on your stack...

Comment: @Pegah, do a re-login. old setting of `ulimit -s` can't be growed in the non-root session.

Comment: Just take a vector<T>& like you should have been doing in the first place.

Comment: The amount of stack space used by the copied vector should not depend on the size of the vector... vectors don't store their elements on the stack. I'm pretty sure that the problem is in the code that was cut out.

Answer (score 3):

I know you've accepted an answer already but your posted code has a problem with the following loop:

```
for(int i=0;i<=v.size();i++)
```

The vector indexes are zero-based. If the vector size is 5 then the valid indexes are 0..4. Your code would try to access elements 0..**5** which is an off-by-one error. I believe your "fix" of the stack size is merely masking other real problems.

In addition, you should be passing the vector by reference, not by value. You are currently copying the vector when you call `AUROC(vector<float> v)`. This is slow and an extravagant waste of memory. Change the function to `AUROC(vector<float> &v)`.

Comment: Thank you so much for checking it. In the main code it is: for(std::vector<long>::size_type i = 0; i != v.size(); i++) which is correct based on what you said. I changed it to AUROC(vector<float> &v) too. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

When you call your function as:

```
vector<float> scores;
// put data in scores;
AUROC(scores);
```

The `scores` vector will be copied into the stack. You should not to pass so large data collections (12 MBytes) via stack, change your code to reference or to pointer passing.

Also, you can check and change stack limits on you Host. On unix:

```
ulimit -s
```

will print the current setting of stacklimit. You can change it by

```
ulimit -s size_in_kb
```

and check it after changing

Comment: Thanks, It worked by changing the stack size in Unix. Cheers. Pegah

Comment: vectors should use no more than like 12-24 bytes on the stack, regardless of their size.

Comment: @Chris Hopman, There can be various implementations of STL. Also this is vector of INT or vector of FLOAT. Also, changing the allowed stacksize helps the topic starter, how can you explain this?

Comment: @Chris Hopman, okay. Seems, the thread opener cite the wrong part of source.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if you might be messing with the stack.

Wrap this

`if (v[i]>0) ++pos; else ++neg;`

in curly braces.

`{ if (v[i]>0) ++pos; else ++neg; }`

Comment: Hi, what do you mean by wrapping?

Comment: the curly here must be a no-op, aren't they?

Comment: for(std::vector<long>::size_type i = 0; i != v.size(); i++)
   {if (v[i]>0) ++pos; else ++neg;} the same error.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
for (long i=0;i<=v.size;i++)
```

should be:

```
for (long i=0;i<=v.size();i++)
```

and similar elsewhere.